# Laravel Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent structured query like this:
Ex.

```
public function showUserWithFriends($username){
   $user = User::where('name','=',$username)->with('friends','friends.jobs')->get()->first();
   return $user;
}
```

This is Query with User, certain username, with his friends and with his friends jobs. But my friends.jobs are json_decoded in SQL database. 
Is there any fancy way to decode it in Model, or should I go to Blade and do the work there?

EDIT:
Code Output:

```
{ 
 'username': 'john.eager',
 'firstname': 'John',
 'lastname: 'Eager'
 'friends': [
     {
       'firstname': 'Marco',
       'lastname': 'Polo',
       'jobs':[
           {
            'data': "{\"1\":\"Software Inc\",\"2\":\"Programmer\",\"3\":\"Salary Great\",\"4\":\"Holiday No\"}"
            }
       ]
     },
     {
       'firstname': 'Dragon',
       'lastname': 'Slayer',
       'jobs':[
           {
            'data': "{\"1\":\"Software Inc\",\"2\":\"Programmer\",\"3\":\"Salary Great\",\"4\":\"Holiday No\"}"
            }
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is `friends.jobs` a column in friends model?

Comment: No friends jobs is relationship between Friend and Job Model, Friend->hasMany->Jobs. It's chained relationship query.

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting with this code?

Comment: Here it is :) It's not real data, but that's that response. String jobs['data'] is json_decoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you work with eloquent you could do the processing in your model and never worry about it. you could also provide a method to do the opposite: to save from a array of jobs to json for the database.

```
class Job extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * will be executed as soon as you call $job->jobs
     *
     * @return array
    public function getData()
    {
        $data = json_decode($this->jobs);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

this works with any property. so if you have `my_pretty_long_attribute` would be `public function getMyPrettyLongAttribute()`.

with your example

```
@foreach ($user->friends as $friends)
    @foreach ($friends->jobs as $job)
        $job->data // <- this will be your [1: "Software Inc", 2: "Programmer", ...] array
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you explain how to use function while Quering Relationship binded data?

Comment: do you have a `User` model and that references a `Friend` model?

Comment: Yes, 
User hasMany Friends
Friends hasMany Jobs

Comment: i updated the code. when you call `$job->data` it then calls your `getData()` method in your `Job` model, since you're requesting the `data` property.